# Mapping dataset to augmentation function does not preserve my original samples

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets, data-augmentation

How should I implement an augmentation pipeline in which my **dataset** gets **extended** instead of **replacing the images** with the augmented ones, that means, how to use map calls to augment and preserve the original samples?

**threads I've checked:** [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55421290/tensorflow-2-0-keras-how-to-write-image-summaries-for-tensorboard/55754700#55754700), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55141076/how-to-apply-data-augmentation-in-tensorflow-2-0-after-tfds-load)

#### **Code I'm currently using:**

```py
records_path = DATA_DIR+'/'+'TFRecords'+TRAIN+'train_0.tfrecord'
# Create a dataset
dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=records_path)
dataset = dataset.map(parsing_fn).cache().map(lambda image, label: (tf.image.central_crop(image,0.5),label))
dataset = dataset.shuffle(100)
dataset = dataset.batch(2)
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
```

I **was expecting** from the code above that by **iterating through batches** I would **get the original image and its cropped version,** besides that i guess that i haven't properly understand **how the cache method behaves.**

Then I have used the code below to exhibit the images, that plots random cropped images.

```py
iterator = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset) 

for i in range(10):
    image,label = iterator.get_next()
    img_array = image[0].numpy()    
    plt.imshow(img_array)
    plt.show()
    print('label: ', label[0])

    img_array = image[1].numpy()    
    plt.imshow(img_array)
    plt.show()
    print('label: ', label[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the `cache()` allows to keep the dataset after applying `parsing_fn` in memory. It only helps on improving the performance. Once you iterate over the whole dataset, everything image is kept in memory. So, the next iteration will be faster as you won't have to apply `parsing_fn` to it again.

If you intend to get the original image and its crop when iterating over the dataset, what you have to do is to return both the image and its crop in your `map()` function:

```py
dataset = dataset.map(parsing_fn).cache().map(lambda image, label: (tf.image.central_crop(image,0.5), image ,label))
```

Then, in your iteration, you can retrieve both:

```py
for i in range(10):
    crop, image, label = iterator.get_next()
```